# Function always returning true despite expected false

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am making a program that checks if a string is contained in a CSV file; however, I keep getting a value of `False` even if the word is contained in the file. Why is my program behaving in a way that it's not returning the correct value?

```
def IS_REGISTERED(avatarName: str):
    csv_list = []
    with open('battle_royale.csv', 'r') as source:
        battleRoyaleData = csv.reader(source, delimiter=',')
        for row in battleRoyaleData:
            csv_list.append(row)
        return any(avatarName in x for x in csv_list)
```

For example, with a sample CSV file containing the following data:

```
'Avatar Name', 'Player Name', ' Player Number'
'LarchDew15', 'Emily', '1'
'Pinerain2', 'Hannah', '2'
'xOakenMaidx', 'Madison', '3'
```

if I pass `'xOakenMaidx'` as an argument for `avatarName` the function returns false despite the CSV containing any value of `'xOakenMaidx'`

Comment: As an side, you can just do `csv_list = list(csv.reader(source, delimiter=','))` and skip the for loop. Also, instead of `if <some boolean condition>: return True else: return False` just do `return <some some condition>`, so instead of the `if -else` statement, just do `return not any(avatarName in x for x in csv_list)`

Comment: It is expected that this function would return `True` when the word is **not** contained in the file. Remove the `not` from `not any(...)` if it was meant to work the other way around.

Comment: Your code works exactly as written. If your input parameter is not in any of the rows, then you are returning True...

Comment: Well, now it returns False for `tree`, so you might want to update the problem you're having

Comment: The CSV data values are all quoted (single quotes). Therefore, you have to include them in your search criterion - e.g. IS_REGISTERED("'LarchDew15'")

Comment: @DarkKnight, That was exactly it, thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out for almost 2 weeks and I never once thought about the quotations

Answer (score 0):

The CSV values have quotations that weren't included in the original query, which meant the values didn't match. Thank you to everyone that helped!